# How do I refactor an API call to use HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter

I have a working API call to Twitter. Yay me! But the problem is is that I would much rather refactor it into HTTParty and then I can extend it later. There are an assortment of reasons as to why I am not using something like the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter). They are mainly due to some limitations that need to be overcome for the application.

Here, I have a working piece of code that calls to Twitter:

```
class Twitter
  def validate
    consumer_key = OAuth::Consumer.new(
      ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'],
      ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
    )
    access_token = OAuth::Token.new(
      ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
      ENV['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']
    )

    baseurl = "https://api.twitter.com"

    address = URI "#{baseurl}/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"

    http = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri
    request.oauth! http, consumer_key, access_token

    http.start
    response = http.request request
    puts "The response status was #{response.code}"
  end
end
```

It is dependent on only the [oath gem](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/).

**Key Question**: How would one wrap this into HTTParty to make it more modular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace `NET::HTTP` with `HTTParty` to get the benefits of the latter, or you could go the extra mile and make your `Twitter` model include `HTTParty` so that it responds to an ActiveRecord-like interface while it abstracts that in the background is issuing all these API requests.

The decision really depends on your needs. Do you just need to issue a specific request to Twitter and display the results or you want to interact more heavily with Twitter and treat it as a model where you can create, retrieve, delete etc.

Regardless of your choice, I believe that the [official readme](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) has all the information you might need (it even has a great example with StackExchange!).

Comment: Yep. I wish I didn't have to go the extra mile to "over-engineer" but I'm in that position. I think it can, ATM, be as simple as reading. I'm not going to think about the writing and DMs. I haven't found anything in the repo yet for oauth...